# Unable to catch a 401 condition using Passport login

Tags: mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I am using PassportJS with Local Strategy and passport-local-mongoose. Here's my login script:

```
// Configure Passport (server.js)
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

.

```
// POST to /login (authenticate.js)
// ---------------------------------------------------------------
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    // server-side validation
  const errors = {
    username: Validator.validateusername(req.body.username),
    password: Validator.validatepassword(req.body.password),
  };
  if (!isEmpty(errors)) return res.send(JSON.stringify({ error: errors }));

  passport.authenticate('local')(req, res, () => {
    // If logged in, we should have user info to send back
    if (req.user) {
      const userdata = JSON.stringify(req.user);
      const token = jwt.sign({
        username: req.user.username,
        firstName: req.user.firstName,
        lastName: req.user.lastName,
        email: req.user.email,
        img: req.user.img,
      }, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      res.cookie('token', token);
      return res.send(userdata);
    }
    // Otherwise return an error
    return res.send(JSON.stringify({ error: 'There was an error logging in' }));
  });
});
```

This works fine except when there's a login error. If the login fails for whatever reason (401 or 500), shouldn't this script return the `There was an error logging in` message? Instead, it just returns a `401 Unauthorized`?

The schema this authentication looks up is:

```
const { mongoose } = require('../config/dbconfig');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const User = new Schema({
  username: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
  password: {
        type: String,
        select: false,
        required: true,
    },
  firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
  lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
  email: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
    },
  img: {
        type: String,
    },
}, { timestamps: true });

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling the strategy a little wrong. You should use it as a middleware, or use the [custom callback](http://passportjs.org/docs/#custom-callback) way. Yours is a kind of mix between these - you call the strategy like it was a middleware but provide your own [`next` middleware function](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html). Since authenticate is called as middleware but no `failureRedirect` option is provided, Passport will [return 401 by default](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/9502d99cf95f90cad2fc9aa1a16da1beefdb8897/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L174). The `next` function is [called when successfully authenticated](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/9502d99cf95f90cad2fc9aa1a16da1beefdb8897/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L263), and in your case it is not the next middleware but a callback function.

To use the custom callback you should write the route handler like this:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  // ...
  passport.authenticate('local', (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (user) {
      // ...
      req.login(user, (err) => {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.send(userdata);
      });
    } else {
      return res.status(401).send({ error: 'There was an error logging in' });
    }
  })(req, res, next);
});
```